# Android: Image resize cause app crash

Tags: android, image-processing, android-webview

I have the following piece of code that is supposed to resize an image after it has been captured from the camera.  Everytime it get to the createScaledBitmap portion it forces the app to close.  Not sure if this piece of information matters but this app is done with webview.

```
private Bitmap resize(String path){
    // create the options
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    //just decode the file
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);

        //get the original size
        int originalHeight = opts.outHeight;
        int originalWidth = opts.outWidth;
        int x = 0, y = 0;
        if(originalHeight > originalWidth){
            if(originalHeight > 1024){
                x = originalHeight / 2;
                y = originalWidth / 2;
            }   
        }
        else if(originalWidth > originalHeight){
            if(originalWidth > 1024){
                x = originalHeight / 2;
                y = originalWidth / 2;
            }
        }
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bp, y, x, false);
        bp = resized;
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path,opts);
        return bp;
```

This is what the logCat outputs when the crash happens.

```
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {mobile311.mobile311webapp/mobile311.mobile311webapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2536)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2578)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:965)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:344)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at mobile311.mobile311webapp.MainActivity.resize(MainActivity.java:173)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at mobile311.mobile311webapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:56)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
01-08 09:05:39.888: E/AndroidRuntime(2292):     ... 11 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in solving the problem I'm having.

Comment: sure bp is not null and x and y has values

Comment: I think here `Bitmap bp` is `null`. I mean `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts)` is returning `null`

Comment: When I look at the variables in debug the height and width details populate for the originalHeight and width and it provides a new x and y value based on the calculation.

Comment: @venom2124 my guess look at the source code is `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);` is returning null.

Comment: I also changed the initialized value of x and y to equal the original height and width that way if the picture was small enough it would just use the original dimensions.

Comment: @venom2124 can you verify that the path is right?

Comment: @Raghunandan Are use saying that even though it is getting the dimensions of the image it still might not be getting access to the actual image file?

Comment: @venom2124 `decodeFile` returns null if the image cannot be decoded. check my post.

Comment: I will post up the bit of code for the openFileChooser function to show you were the variable that contained the file path is coming from if that helps.

Comment: File imageStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Mobile311_Citizen");
             fullUrl = imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
             file = new File(fullUrl);

Comment: That is the code that creates the file path that I'm trying to recall to resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the code that I ended up with the get everything to work.  I also added a time/date stamp to the resized image as well.

```
private Bitmap resize(String path) throws IOException{
    // create the options
        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    //just decode the file
        opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        System.out.print(path);
        //uses the file path to 
        Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);

        //get the original size
        double height = opts.outHeight;
        double width = opts.outWidth;

        //checks orientation of the image and decreases the size of the dimensions
        while(width > 1280 || height > 1024){
            width = width * .9;
            height = height * .9;
        }

        //creates the new scaled bitmap image
        Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bp, (int)width, (int)height, true);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); // reading local time in the system 

        Canvas cs = new Canvas(resized); //used for drawing on a bitmap
        Paint tPaint = new Paint(); //object that we're adding to the bitmap
        tPaint.setTextSize(35); 
        tPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE); 
        tPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
        cs.drawBitmap(resized, 0f, 0f, null); //place the original image in our bitmap
        float height1 = tPaint.measureText("yY"); //get an offset based on textsize
        cs.drawText(dateTime, 20f, height1+15f, tPaint); //place the text on the canvas

        //outputs the new bitmap image to the sd card for upload later
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        resizedUrl = sdCardRoot + File.separator + "IMG_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
        saveImg = new File(resizedUrl);
        fOut = new FileOutputStream(saveImg);
        resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.close();
        return resized;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

bmp is null. Meaning that your `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` returned null. Make sure that the file path you enter is an actual valid file path. `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` returns null if the file cannot be decoded, so if this file doesn't exist it can not be decoded (this is the most common cause).

Comment: What would be the easiest way to get the correct file path if the image is being captured by the native camera.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code (2.3 rev1). `bp` is null indicating null returned by `BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);`

```
public static Bitmap decodeFile (String pathName, BitmapFactory.Options opts)

Added in API level 1
Decode a file path into a bitmap. If the specified file name is null, or cannot be decoded into a bitmap, the function returns null.

Parameters
pathName    complete path name for the file to be decoded.
opts    null-ok; Options that control downsampling and whether the image should be completely decoded, or just is size returned.
Returns
The decoded bitmap, or null if the image data could not be decoded, or, if opts is non-null, if opts requested only the size be returned (in opts.outWidth and opts.outHeight)
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/graphics/Bitmap.java/

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:344)


331     public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth,
332             int dstHeight, boolean filter) {
333         Matrix m;
334         synchronized (Bitmap.class) {
335             // small pool of just 1 matrix
336             m = sScaleMatrix;
337             sScaleMatrix = null;
338         }
339 
340         if (m == null) {
341             m = new Matrix();
342         }
343 
344         final int width = src.getWidth(); // src is the Bitmap
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set `inJustDecodeBounds` flag to `true` for `Options`, `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` returns `null` and this may help you...

```
private Bitmap resize(String path) {
    // create the options
    BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    // just decode the file
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);

    // get the original size
    int originalHeight = opts.outHeight;
    int originalWidth = opts.outWidth;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (originalHeight > originalWidth) {
        if (originalHeight > 1024) {
            x = originalHeight / 2;
            y = originalWidth / 2;
        }
    } else if (originalWidth > originalHeight) {
        if (originalWidth > 1024) {
            x = originalHeight / 2;
            y = originalWidth / 2;
        }
    }
    opts.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    opts.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(originalWidth, originalHeight, x, y);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, opts);
    return bitmap;
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(int width, int height,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

make sure that your File path is valid...

my great thanks to http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: This solution will stop the app from crashing but still does not create a scaled version of the file I need.  I almost think that when I capture and save it's not saving the file where and how I want it.